# Ubuntu: Eclipse doesn't see ADT plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, adt

I try to open my android sdk on Linux ubuntu 12.10. I installed latest Eclipse Juno

```
sudo tar -zxvf ./eclipse-SDK-4.2.1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz -C /opt
```

installed adroid sdk:

```
sudo tar -zxvf ./android-sdk_r21.1-linux.tgz -C /opt
```

In Eclipse I installed latest GEF and WST Server Adapters, than added ADT plugin from

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

But in my `Windows > Preferences` or anywhere I don't see my android plugin. Eclipse is still without ADT. Why?

Comment: did you check http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html  for installation on Linux?

Comment: I recently able to installed eclipse on Ubuntu, and those steps were helpful,  Here are the steps to install Java and Eclipse, prior to installing the Android SDK and ADT Plugin.

    If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine, you need to install the ia32-libs package using apt-get::

    apt-get install ia32-libs

    Next, install Java:

    apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I solve it. Lame way: just set `chmod 777` to `/opt/eclipse` & `/opt/android-sdk-linux` and reload adt plugin.